# FaceFeatures - How to better customise the details of JSON output file?

Tags: scripting, json-format

I am using FacialFeatures to identify the age and gender of characters in movie frames.

I am using the following script (simplified from [this source](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2288529)):

```
formatFacialFeatures[x_]:=If[Length[x[[2]]]==0,{x[[1]]->"None"},{x[[1]]->({
    "Age" -> #[["Age"]],
    "Gender" -> #[["Gender"]]
    }&)/@ x[[2]]}]

pathToFolder = $ScriptCommandLine[[2]]
pathToJSON = $ScriptCommandLine[[3]]

pathImgs = FileNames[All, pathToFolder];

extract = formatFacialFeatures /@ Transpose@{ FileNameTake/@pathImgs,FacialFeatures[Import/@pathImgs, features]};

Export[pathToJSON, extract];
Print["Done."]
```

After running this script on windows cmd prompt, I obtain this JSON file:

```
    {
        "photo1.jpeg":[
            {
                "Age":17,
                "Gender":"Female"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "photo2.jpeg":[
            {
                "Age":28,
                "Gender":"Male"
            },
            {
                "Age":30,
                "Gender":"Female"
            }
        ]
    }, [...]
```

I am struggling to turn this JSON file into a dataframe which I could handle for analysis (I have tried with both R and pandas).

A possible problem I have identified is that there are no field linked to the photos and to the faces identified in the photos.

For instance, I would like to obtain a JSON file which looks like:

```
    {
        "Photo ID":"photo1.jpeg":[
            {
                "Face ID": 1,
                "Age":17,
                "Gender":"Female"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Photo ID":"photo2.jpeg":[
            {
                "Face ID": 2,
                "Age":28,
                "Gender":"Male"
            },
            {
                "Face ID": 3,
                "Age":30,
                "Gender":"Female"
            }
        ]
    }, [...]
```

How can I modify the script to add these information?

Regards,
Hugo.

Comment: This does not look like a valid json: `{ "Photo ID":"photo1.jpeg":[]}`, I mean the key `"x":"y"`, right?

Comment: You are right, this is not a valid json. I was just giving it as an example to illustrate what I am aiming at, which is to say field names for each photo and each face. Am I being clear?